# Async/Await -> Possible without return value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

So, I have a function which does some asynchronous work.

The function currently looks like this (`setTimeout` currently is implemented because I haven't managed to implement the `async`/`await` way correctly):

```js
function gatherAllRelevantReservationData(TimeFrameStartFromInputfield, TimeFrameEndFromInputfield, liebraum, liebsitz, reservationFromDatabaseTimeFramesStart, reservationFromDatabaseTimeFramesEnd){

    console.log("reservationFromDatabaseTimeFramesStart inside gatherAllRelevantReservationData are ", reservationFromDatabaseTimeFramesStart, reservationFromDatabaseTimeFramesEnd)
    //console.log("TimeFrameStartFromInputfield and TimeFrameEndFromInputfield inside gatherAllRelevantReservationData are ", TimeFrameStartFromInputfield, TimeFrameEndFromInputfield)
    var timeFrameAsObject = convertDateStringToJavaScriptDateTimeObject(TimeFrameStartFromInputfield, TimeFrameEndFromInputfield)
    var startDateAsObject = timeFrameAsObject.start
    var endDateAsObject =  timeFrameAsObject.end
    var timeFrameAsUnixTimeStamp = ConvertToCustomizedUnixTimestampString(startDateAsObject, endDateAsObject)
    var startDateAsUnixTimeStamp  = timeFrameAsUnixTimeStamp.start;
    var endDateAsUnixTimeStamp = timeFrameAsUnixTimeStamp.end;
    getTable(startDateAsUnixTimeStamp, endDateAsUnixTimeStamp, liebraum);

    if(FavSeatcheckHasBeenEnabled == 1){
    setTimeout(function(){
       prepareSelectedAndDatabaseDateStringsForComparison(startDateAsObject, endDateAsObject, liebraum, liebsitz, reservationFromDatabaseTimeFramesStart, reservationFromDatabaseTimeFramesEnd);
    }, 300)
  }
};
```

The `getTable` function requires some time and needs to have finished before `prepareSelectedAndDatabaseDateStringsForComparison` is called. The problem is that `getTable` doesn't have any return value.

I'm pretty new to ES7 `async`/`await` features as well as to ES6 promises. 
I know that await usually expects some promise to be returned, and I probably could arrange this in some very hacky, nasty way.

But I'd like to know if there is any other, elegant way around this.

Ideally, I'd just like to attach `async` to `gatherAllRelevantReservationData` and then put an "await" in front of `getTable` call, but this of course did not work.

Any ideas how I could solve this?

EDIT: Here is the "getTable" function:

```js
function getTable(start, ende, liebraum)
{
//console.log("start in getTable is " + start)
//console.log("ende in getTable is " + ende)
  fillRooms(liebraum);
  $.post("../include/returnTable.php", {
    anfang: start,
    ende: ende,
    art: art
  }, function(data){
    document.getElementById("tablediv").innerHTML= data;
    console.log("start inside callback of AJAX inside getTabel is ", start)
    //console.log("data after getTable function " + data);
 //fillRooms(liebraum);
  })

}
```

Comment: What exactly is `getTable`?

Comment: Without knowing how `getTable` looks like internally or a documentation how to use it, it is not possible to tell. An asynchronous function has to either return a Promise, accept a callback, or has to be event driven. If non of them is true, then that function can be considered as broken.

Comment: @t.niese I edited the getTable function into the post.

Comment: If `getTable` didn't return anything, how would `await` know *what* to wait for? There is no "detect asynchrony" magic.

Comment: "*expects some promise to be returned, and I probably could arrange this in some very hacky, nasty way.*" - what is hacky and nasty about adding a `return` in front of `$.post()` to return the promise that the ajax call already creates?

Comment: @Bergi probably nothing :D I just didn't know that it could be done this way, thanks BRB! ;)

Comment: @Bergi Just for the future: Let's assume there is a $.post which has some stuff it does inside the successCallback. Does the "return" in front of the "$.post" return the promise once the $.post has succeed, or once the successcallback has finished as well?

Comment: @ForeFather321 To be sure, don't use a success callback. Use `.then()` instead, which returns a promise for the result of the callback (so definitely resolves after the callback has been called). *(That said, the `success` callback is installed first and will run before other stuff on the promise)*

Comment: @Bergi Um, okay, how does this look like syntax-wise?
$.post("URL", {AJAX-Request-Code}).then()
???

Comment: @ForeFather321 `return $.post("…", {…}).then(function(data){
    …
  })`

Comment: @Bergi thanks! :=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to use `async`/`await`, you need to change `getTable` to return a `Promise` (or some thenable), because only they can be `await`ed.

Fix your `getTable` to return the `$.post` call, so that its success can then be detected in `gatherAllRelevantReservationData` function, and then you can simply `await` the call of `getTable`:

```
async function gatherAllRelevantReservationData(...) {
  ...
  await getTable(...);
  ...
}
function getTable(start, ende, liebraum) {
  fillRooms(liebraum);
  return $.post("../include/returnTable.php", {
    anfang: start,
    ende: ende,
    art: art
  }, function(data) {
    document.getElementById("tablediv").innerHTML = data;
  })
}
```